# Rearranging items in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to implement a rearranging feature to my app. The data is taken from SQLite db. I find Drag&Drop function when the item is long pressed kind of problematic. No enough experience to implement it. Therefore, I would like to know are there any other methods to allow rearranging? For example, press some button after which items are free to move and at the end, you press save, like in iOS.

Comment: look at this library https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf) and [this](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-6a6f0c422efd) can help you. It is a very good tutorial about how to use the Android native `ItemTouchHelper` to rearrange and set actions to the different item movements.